# powershell Saving CDATA content in xml file to text with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

How can I save the content of the CDATA section of an xml file to a text file?

file.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

<template format_id="1.8" >
<content><![CDATA[ Windows 7 önceki sistemler olan Windows Vista ve XP’den her ne kadar hızlı olsa bile yine de çok sayıda kusur barındırıyor. Bir kere Windows 7 yüklü bir bilgisayarı kullanmaya başladıktan kısa bir süre sonra yavaşlamalar, kasmalar, takılmalar ve diğer bazı hatalar baş gösterecektir. Fakat tüm bunlara mahkum değilsiniz. Bu sayfada açıklayacağım kısa ve öz tavsiyelerle kesin olarak bilgisayarınızı en az 2 kat hızlandıracaksınız.
1- İlk olarak bilgisayarınıza ihtiyacınız dışında program kurmayın ve Program Ekle/Kaldır‘ı açıp işinize yaramayan veya ayda yılda bir kullandığınız tüm programları kaldırın. Çünkü bunlar gereksiz yere bilgisayarın yavaşlamasına sebep olur.
2- Başlangıçta otomatik çalışan gereksiz programları temizlemek için başlat menüsündeki arama satırına ''msconfig'' (tırnak işaretleri hariç) yazın ve çıkan sonuca çift tıklayıp açın. Açılan pencerede üstteki menülerden Başlangıç’a tıklayın. Açılan listedeki programlar bilgisayarınızı her açtığınızda otomatik olarak açılıyor ve bilgisayarı hem kasıyor hem de geç açılmasını sağlıyor. Bu programlar içinden zorunlu olanlar dışındakileri devre dışı bırakın. Bana teşekkür edeceksiniz.
3- Bilgisayar bakım programlarının çoğu işe yaramaz çöplüktür ve daha çok bilgisayara zarar verir. Dünyada tüm ünlü teknoloji bloglarının hep bir ağızdan tavsiye ettiği tek bakım programı CCleaner programıdır. Tamamen Türkçe olan CCleaner bilgisayarı onarır, bakım yapar ve hızlandırır. Gereksiz dosyaları siler, disk birleştirerek sistemi optimize eder ve gereksiz tarayıcı eklentilerini temizler. Özellikler programın içinde hazır olarak gelen Disk birleştirme aracını çalıştırın, çok memnun kalacaksınız. 
4- Windows 7’nin en kötü yanı aslında kullanıcıların yüzde doksanının hiçbir zaman kullanmadığı bir sürü programı içermesidir. Bu programlar hem boşuna yer kaplar, hem boşuna sisteme yük bindirir hem de kafa karıştırır. Şimdi aşağıdaki listede verdiğim bu hizmetleri kişisel ihtiyacınıza göre optimize ederek bilgisayarı epey rahatlatabilir ve performansını arttırabilirsiniz
]]></content><properties><pageFormat mediaSizeName="1" leftMargin="42.51968479156494" rightMargin="42.51968479156494" topMargin="42.51968479156494" bottomMargin="14.17322826385498" paperOrientation="1" headerFOffset="15.0" footerFOffset="60.0" /></properties>
<elements >
<paragraph LineSpacing="0.0" LeftIndent="0.0" TabSet="54.0:2:0" resolver="hvl-default" SpaceBelow="1.0" SpaceAbove="1.0" RightIndent="0.0" Hanging="0.0" Alignment="0"><content resolver="hvl-default" bold="true" startOffset="0" length="6" /></paragraph><paragraph LineSpacing="0.0" LeftIndent="0.0" TabSet="54.0:2:0" resolver="hvl-default" SpaceBelow="1.0" SpaceAbove="1.0" RightIndent="0.0" Hanging="0.0" Alignment="0"><tab resolver="hvl-default" bold="true" startOffset="6" length="1" /><field resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="il_Ilce" isList="false" startOffset="7" length="8" /><content resolver="hvl-default" bold="true" startOffset="15" length="1" /></paragraph><paragraph LineSpacing="0.0" LeftIndent="0.0" TabSet="54.0:2:0" resolver="hvl-default" SpaceBelow="1.0" SpaceAbove="1.0" RightIndent="0.0" Hanging="0.0" Alignment="0"><tab resolver="hvl-default" bold="true" startOffset="16" length="1" /><field resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="17" length="3" /><space resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="20" length="1" /><field resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="21" length="4" /><space resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="25" length="1" /><field resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="26" length="4" /><space resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="30" length="1" /><field resolver="hvl-default" fieldType="1" bold="true" fieldName="mahkemeAdi" isList="false" startOffset="31" length="9" /><content resolver="hvl-default" startOffset="40" length="1" /></paragraph><paragraph LineSpacing="0.0" resolver="hvl-default" LeftIndent="0.0"
```

This is the desired output:

```
Windows 7 önceki sistemler olan Windows Vista ve XP’den her ne kadar hızlı olsa bile yine de çok sayıda kusur barındırıyor. Bir kere Windows 7 yüklü bir bilgisayarı kullanmaya başladıktan kısa bir süre sonra yavaşlamalar, kasmalar, takılmalar ve diğer bazı hatalar baş gösterecektir. Fakat tüm bunlara mahkum değilsiniz. Bu sayfada açıklayacağım kısa ve öz tavsiyelerle kesin olarak bilgisayarınızı en az 2 kat hızlandıracaksınız.
1- İlk olarak bilgisayarınıza ihtiyacınız dışında program kurmayın ve Program Ekle/Kaldır‘ı açıp işinize yaramayan veya ayda yılda bir kullandığınız tüm programları kaldırın. Çünkü bunlar gereksiz yere bilgisayarın yavaşlamasına sebep olur.
2- Başlangıçta otomatik çalışan gereksiz programları temizlemek için başlat menüsündeki arama satırına ''msconfig'' (tırnak işaretleri hariç) yazın ve çıkan sonuca çift tıklayıp açın. Açılan pencerede üstteki menülerden Başlangıç’a tıklayın. Açılan listedeki programlar bilgisayarınızı her açtığınızda otomatik olarak açılıyor ve bilgisayarı hem kasıyor hem de geç açılmasını sağlıyor. Bu programlar içinden zorunlu olanlar dışındakileri devre dışı bırakın. Bana teşekkür edeceksiniz.
3- Bilgisayar bakım programlarının çoğu işe yaramaz çöplüktür ve daha çok bilgisayara zarar verir. Dünyada tüm ünlü teknoloji bloglarının hep bir ağızdan tavsiye ettiği tek bakım programı CCleaner programıdır. Tamamen Türkçe olan CCleaner bilgisayarı onarır, bakım yapar ve hızlandırır. Gereksiz dosyaları siler, disk birleştirerek sistemi optimize eder ve gereksiz tarayıcı eklentilerini temizler. Özellikler programın içinde hazır olarak gelen Disk birleştirme aracını çalıştırın, çok memnun kalacaksınız. 
4- Windows 7’nin en kötü yanı aslında kullanıcıların yüzde doksanının hiçbir zaman kullanmadığı bir sürü programı içermesidir. Bu programlar hem boşuna yer kaplar, hem boşuna sisteme yük bindirir hem de kafa karıştırır. Şimdi aşağıdaki listede verdiğim bu hizmetleri kişisel ihtiyacınıza göre optimize ederek bilgisayarı epey rahatlatabilir ve performansını arttırabilirsiniz.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following which uses Powershell with Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test.txt"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$content = $doc.Descendants('content')[0].Value

Write-Output $content > $outputFilename
```

Comment: You are great, thank you very much